# DC Motor EMF re-usage?

Tags: dc-motor, emf

I have 2 questions:

1 - The Brushed DC motor variety has a type when one turns the shaft manually it free runs with no friction or resistance at all, and then another type which feels like a mild step friction/resistance as though magnets inside causing some type of resistance when the shaft passes them? Which type are these and what is the difference.

2 - The type causing a mild friction does not allow the motor shaft to return to it's original starting position. If say you have a string attached to the motor with the other end of the string attached to like an elastic yarn that the motor extends it to it's stall point and when the current is cut off.

I need it to free flow to the original starting point the the elastic band helps it do that but because of the stepping like friction of the shaft it does not quite unwind and return to the original position because the motor resistance.

I am thinking is it possible to use the EMF energy to give the motor a kick in the opposite direction?

thanks

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please format it. 1) Depends on the motor, you'll need to give some motor constants 2) The only EMF that your going to use to move the motor is voltage you supply, you can get some cogging in a BLDC motor but not much 3) Motors also have inertia

Comment: Thanks for your response, one question was about different types of Motor, that Mr. Cowie below helped solve that question that in fact it's the Brushed permanent-magnet DC motors causing the step resistance each time passing air gaps. The second question was about how can one capture the produced back EMF at current cut off and direct it back to the motor to shock the opposite direction to produce even a half turn.

Comment: Dont you know when you hit Enter on your keyboard  a new paragraph is created?

Comment: @soosaisteven Don't you know that what you said is incorrect and that the correct result depends on whether you are editing a question/answer or a comment. (Assuming that your "information" relates to this site.
Comment: Enter -> terminate
Answer/Question. -> No effect - text runs on. needs, 2 spaces + Enter to give NL, and 2 x Enter to give new paragraph.

Comment: Quant - It is generally considered that rather than tell us how you think you may be able to solve a less than fully explained problem, you should major on telling us in adequate detail what you actually want to achieve and what components you wish to use and why. That allows people who may know how to meet your need know what the need is.

Comment: Russell McMahon, thanks for explaining the "ENTER" issue to  soosai steven. I had even tried the Control+Enter(as in Telegram) which did not work, I just tried "space+space+enter" also "2 x Enter to give new paragraph" which again neither worked! Being an engineering site, it's kind of surprising how the editor's functionalities are not up to-date and more ergonomic?!

Comment: Russell McMahon - Part one of the question was answered by Charles Cowie & Olin Lathrop very descriptively and sufficiently below regarding the Cogging issue. "New Paragraph" The second part of the question was also explained and clarified below is that: Is it possible to collect and use the back EMF to give a momentarily shock to the DC motor in the opposite direction without the need to have an H-Bridge?

Comment: There are many applications where the EMF is being used for different purposes already as in the  Electrical buses where every time the Bus brakes the generated Back EMF is collected and directed towards recharging the battery, so I needed to know how the circuitry should be if at all possible for collecting the EMF on a micro dc motor after driving it first to stall and then cutting the current to the motor after 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The second type is a brushless DC motor with Hall Effect internal commutation or a stepper motor with stronger magnetic attraction for pulse rotation with a full bridge from phase to phase.

The resting position is determined by the closest magnetic pole position and will be random. Shorting out the coil after power off will stop it more abruptly.  Sensing rotor position can be used to control it's stop position if you wanted, but shunting the motor would effectively shunt the BEMF voltage to maximize current to brake the motor.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The 2nd type is not a stepper nor a brush-less motor, it only has 2 wires. It always stops after stalling during the stretching of the rubber band and is on for 1 second at which point the mosfets cut the current and the rubber band unwinds it to near the no load position, if I eliminate the EMF diode would the motor reverse momentarily and help with the unwinding?

Answer (score 2):

What you are feeling is the difference between high and low *cogging*.  Brushed DC motors have permanent magnets to create the static magnetic field.  These are attracted to points of the poles on the rotor.  The effect feels somewhat like a detent per pole of rotation.

Some motors either use windings to create the static magnetic field, or the magnetic material of the poles are shaped in such a way that there is little detent feeling, called cogging, per magnetic cycle.  The kind with field windings (instead of permanent magnets) always rotate in the same direction regardless of the voltage polarity.  These type of motors work on both DC or AC.  The reason is that a voltage polarity change flips the sign of both the stator and rotor fields.  When you have two magnets and you flip both of them, they will repel or attract as before.  Mathematically, flipping both magnets is like changing the sign twice.

Answer (score 1):

A brushed DC motor that feels like it has magnets inside that cause a resistance to manual rotation of the shaft is a brushed-type, permanent-magnet DC motor. The resistance that is felt is exactly what it feels like. There is nothing other than mechanically holding the shaft that will make the motor stop or remain in a position that is not "preferred" by the configuration of the magnets.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the type. Please note the motor stops every time at stall point and I don't have a problem with that but, after cutting current it does not unwind to the original No Load position so if did 6 exact turns to the stall point it under the rubber band pull back force unwinds/free flows by itself to say 5.5 turns and stops 0.5 turn short because the magnetic resistance surpasses the rubber band.does eliminating the diode or some type of simple circuitry I could shock it to do a minimal rotation in the reverse direction but short of implementing an H-Bridge?

Comment: Removing the diode won't help. I can't think of anything simple to do what you want. Even an H bridge may be difficult because of the need to get just the right timing or else have a switch or sensor to determine shaft position.

Comment: A brushed DC motor with a wound field would provide better freewheeling, but would be difficult if not impossible to find in a very small size.

Comment: Thanks again for you time, in case of the H-Bridge absolutely it must be used in conjunction with a sensor but, it still beats me why the generated back EMF can't be used at current cut off and to direct it back to opposite poles to shock the reverse direction! I read somewhere on Electric buses every time it brakes they collect the EMF to recharge the Bus' battery with. Regardless I guess even if possible the circuitry would be more complicated than the H-B.

Comment: The electric vehicle operation that you describe is 4-quadrant control. An H bridge is used. Braking with energy dissipated in resistance can be accomplished more simply, but energy recovery and reverse torque can not.